# Из-за @JsonFormat теряется один день

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

В своем проекте использую библиотеку Jackson для сериализации объектов в JSON. При использовании @JsonFormat устанавливается дата на один день раньше. Например, я задаю 10.03.1990, а получается 09.03.1990.

Использую следующий синтаксис:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy")
```

Comment: Вряд ли это из-за использования @JsonFormat. Скорее всего проблема в типе объекта, в который дата записывается. Попробуйте послать дату в другом месяце. Возможно идет учет перевода времени и дата сбрасывается на час вперед/назад, а т.к. формат dd.MM.yyyy, то возможно дата интерпретируется как 10.03.1990T00:00:00, а тогда сдвиг на час назад как раз и даст результат 09.03.1990.

Comment: @learp Установил timezone как "Europe/Moscow" и все заработало.
`@JsonFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy", timezone="Europe/Moscow")`